# React query-useInfiniteQuery

Tags: react-hooks, react-query

I am using useInfiniteQuery to fetch data on a page a scroll. I have a few factors like filters, sort etc based on which my query result will change.

I have a query key defined but when filter changes the data is not refreshed it picks up the old filter data.

How should this be resolved ?
Is there anything similar to dependency array as in useEffect ?

Can we add the dependencies in addition to Query key?

Ex:useInfiniteQuery[key, all the dependencies as comma separated  values]

Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: If you change the queryKey, the query should retrigger and present a new result. Can you share some code?

Comment: useInfiniteQuery(["posts", filter, sort], queryfn..).  - here whenever the filter changes or the sort value changes i want to refetch. Also if the same filter is accessed again in the cache window it should not refetch. Is it correct understanding ?

Comment: Difficult to judge. A code sandbox of the full thing would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything similar to dependency array as in useEffect ?
> Can we add the dependencies in addition to Query key?

Yes, all "dependencies" of your query should go to the query key. This ensures that they are cached separately and you'll get automatic refetches when the key changes

- https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key
- https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query#treat-the-query-key-like-a-dependency-array

There is now also an eslint rule that will warn you if you're using something in your queryFn that is *not* part of the key: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/eslint/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Thank you so much for the references. It really helped and solved the problem.